# What algorithm would I use to implement a modified graph search problem?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

A car trip where there are gas stations with unlimited gasoline and parts for one time use.The parts permanately increase the size of the gas tank (measured in mileage) but the parts, once used, cannot be used again. The car itself originally has a tank that can travel a certain number of miles. What would be the best way to find out the initial minimum gas tank size needed to traverse between two Gas Stations as well as finding out what gas stations can be initially traversed using a certain gas tank?

I initially tried Dijkstra but it doesn't work on negative values and I don't think a Minimum Spanning Tree is the best because it doesn't necessairly minimize the distance between two nodes. My initial thought would be to find an algorithm that can return the total minimized edge weights (including negatives) of two values but not sure how to do that

Comment: Hi! Interesting question. I'm just slightly confused by the beginning: are the reservoir-increases permanent, or one-time-use?

Comment: Since the gas stations have unlimited gas, the exact distance between two nodes is not really important - the only important thing is whether that distance is more or less than what the car is currently able to travel. For instance, if my reservoir currently allows me to travel up to 20km, and I have to choose to go to a node that is 18km away or to another node which is 15km away, I won't lose anything by going to the node that is 18km away, since once I arrive I can replenish my tank anyway.

Comment: @Stef The resevoir-increases can only be used once but once used, they increase the size of the tank forever. So if my original tank size is 10 miles and then gas station A has parts of 5 and I go there; now my gas tank is 15 miles.

Comment: @Stef - that is true so you would have a variable that keeps track of the distance between gas stations (you can't go to any station where you have more distance than mileage) but having those two variables but then there is the graph choice of which one you go to and not. I'm confused though on choosing which station to go to; not sure Dijstra or MST are helpful here

Comment: You've mixed up describing the problem and describing your ideas of a solution. In particular the idea of negative edge weights seems confused. Dijkstra doesn't seem appropriate, because there's no concept of minimizing distance in the problem -- only whether you can get from A to B with a particular size of gas tank.

Comment: A heuristic algorithm would try to assess which neighbouring nodes are interesting to go to first. A node is interesting if it contains a big reservoir-increase, or if it has not been reached yet, or if it has interesting reachable neighbours.

Comment: Seems like you have a set of stations you can visit (initially only the first one), and then you can expand that set by any station within the capacity of your gas tank from any of the stations in your set, and then update the gastank size with all of the parts from any station you can reach. Repeat until you get stuck or the target station is within your set. That solves it for an initial-sized gas tank. You can binary search to find a minimal initial gas-tank size.

Comment: @PaulHankin For seeing whether a certain gas station is reachable with an initial gas station and a tank size, would a greedy algorithm to always take the largest reachable gas station and then see if the desired node is reachable with current milege and if not, go to the largest reachable again?

Comment: Any algorithm that makes progress (when it is possible) works, including greedy. Because there's never a wrong choice as you can always go back to a previously visited gas station.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key observation is that if you can get to any *n* different gas stations, then you can go to *all* of them, collect all of their gas tank enhancements, and drive around between all reachable stations however much you like.

Since it only matters which stations you can connect to, you don't have to remember anything about the paths required to get there, and you can solve this using a simple variant of an MST algorithm.

As we perform Prim's algorithm, for example, we can keep track of the total size of all reachable gas tank augments.

Perform Prim's algorithm starting at the initial station, until you get to the destination.  Whenever you add a new station, subtract the current total augment size from the edge distance to figure out how much initial tank it takes to get there.  Then add the station's augment to your total.

Your answer is the maximum initial tank requirement that you discover until you reach the destination.

Comment: Assuming this is a planar, Euclidean graph, we should be able to improve Prim's performance by limiting edges to the Delaunay triangulation.

Answer (score 1):

A basic algorithm can work as follows.

> 1. Keep a collection of unreached stations, with the distance from the
>    currently reachable stations set initially to infinity, except for the
>    initial station, for which the distance is empty.
> 2. Pick the station with the lowest distance. If it's above the capacity
>    of the fuel tank, then you're stuck.
> 3. If the station is the target station, then you've succeeded.
> 4. Otherwise, update the distances of any unvisited stations immediately adjacent
>    to the chosen station with the distances from this new station (if doing so reduces their distance). Update
>    the capacity of the fuel tank with the part in the current station.
>
> Repeat from step 2, "Pick the station..."

This gives you a method to find whether a particular station is reachable given an initial fuel tank size.

It's easy to modify this algorithm to find the minimal initial fuel tank size needed to reach the target station. Start with a fuel tank of size 0, and every time you get stuck (in step 2), increase that initial fuel tank size just enough that you're not stuck.

For the set of unreached stations, you can use a Fibonacci heap as in Dijkstra's algorithm to get O(m + n log n) runtime (m = total number of roads, n = total number of gas stations).

Comment: Maybe clarify step 4 to indicate only to do those updates that reduce distance.

Comment: Reduce distance?

Comment: @ArronStarmer I'm not clear what you're asking, but if for a particular station its current distance (as represented in the algorithm) is D and there's a road of length R from the new station to that station, then you set the new distance to min(D, R). That is, you update the distance if doing so reduces the distance.

Comment: Oh, I guess I should have clarified that there is a road between every gas station and every other gas station